# Typescript generated javascript (minified through gulp) loss its handler when calling it in another javascript

Tags: typescript, uglifyjs

Hi I have a very simple Typescript module

```
export module myFirstPackage {
    export class test {
        description : string
        constructor() {
            this.description = "This is a test module class";
        }

        public getDescription() {
            return this.description;
        }

    }

    export function printDescription() : string {
        alert(new test().getDescription);
    }
}
```

I generated javascript file and uglified it, I try then use the uglified file in another javascript application as library, but how can I get the handler to the ts generated javascript? I can't access it through my module name at all.

I am uglifyingt it through gulp

my gulp file looks like the following

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var watchify = require("watchify");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require("tsify");
var gutil = require("gulp-util");
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

//Variables
var conf = {
    html: ['src/html/**/*.html'],
    scss: ['src/scss/**/*.scss'],
    jsdistAll: 'src/js/',
    jsdist: 'www/js/',
    htmldist: 'www/templates/',
    cssdist: 'www/css/',
    jsfilename: 'all.js',
    cssfilename: 'style.css',
    tsentry: 'src/ts/main.ts',
    debugts: true
};
//TS code handling
var watchedBrowserify = watchify(browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: conf.debugts,
    entries: [conf.tsentry],
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {}
}).plugin(tsify));

function bundle() {
    return watchedBrowserify
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(conf.jsfilename))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.jsdistAll))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.jsdist));
}

watchedBrowserify.on("update", bundle);
watchedBrowserify.on("log", gutil.log);

//Html handling
gulp.task("html", function () {
    return gulp.src(conf.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.htmldist));
});

//Css handling
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(conf.scss)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({includePaths : ['_/'+conf.scss]}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.cssdist))
        .pipe(minifyCss({
            keepSpecialComments: 0
        }))
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.cssdist))
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(conf.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(conf.sass, ['sass']);
});

//initialize task
gulp.task("default", ["html", "sass", "watch"], bundle);
```

Another question on the row is watch works for html but not for sass.

Comment: Ofcourse I can always manually export the module by explicit connect module to the window object, but I though I don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with minification, but with browserify scoping your module (as it should be). You need to tell browserify to explicitly expose your module and the require function.

Add to your browserify chain in gulp:

```
.require(fooFilename, { expose: "foo" })
```

...and in your other half of the project:

```
var foo = require("foo");
foo.fooExport;
```

Standard minification should never have an effect on **anything** accessible, by the way.

**On the other hand** you could simply **not use ES6 modules**, which happens when you remove the top level export statement in front of the namespace (you're using the old *module* keyword there, but this is actually known as *namespace* now). In this case you won't need browserify, just *gulp-typescript* or something and concat your output.

Comment: I think the problem here would be I am try to call it in a no nodes application, in ionic frontend, I need the module to be exposed globally without any require needed.

Comment: Then remove the top level export before myFirstPackage and do not use browserify, which sole purpose is to bundle node like modules for in-browser usage.